# Why setVisibility() does work in for-statement?

Tags: android, for-loop, android-imageview

There are a lot of questions on this topic but none whose answers solve my problem.

I have an array of `ImageView` and, through a for-statement, I would like to get them `INVISIBLE`. The code is the following.

```
final ImageView[] image = new ImageView[12];

image[0]  = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
image[1]  = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
image[2]  = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
image[3]  = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView4);

for (int p = 0; p < 4; p++) {
    image[p].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

It seems that the problem is putting `p` as argument of `image[]`, I think so because if I put a number instead of `p` it works.

Comment: `p` is a number.

Comment: This should compile. Is this a runtime problem? If so, please add the stack trace to the question. Althought in that case, it would probably be a `NullPointerException` caused by an wrong id given to `findViewById()`.

Comment: @AhamadAnees I don't know, if I write for example `image[2]` it works, and if I write `image[p]` it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use this it uses `Varargs`

```
 public void hideViews(View... views)
    {   //it will work with parent class but you can change it to ImageView
        for (View view : views) {
            view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }
```

and the call:

```
hideViews(image1,image2,image3,image4);
```

good luck;

Comment: thanks, but what is written between `View... views`?

Comment: @user7867367 its called Varargs read more [here](https://www.javatpoint.com/varargs) , upvote the question if you found it helpful